# Is it possible to use asp.net web forms without viewstate and postbacks

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, javascript-framework

Maybe title is not clear enough.
I must use asp.net web forms it is a requirement and can't do anything about it.
I want to avoid server controls (like grids, dropdowns etc.)
I want to use ajax for most actions and use front end like angular or knockout.
And I want to build one web api project for all backend actions.
So code behind views wlill be minimal, web api will be core action handler.
What I need as answer to this question is all about architecture.
Is this what I am planning to do natural way to make app?
Or this is completly wrong way to do things?

Comment: could you clarify why web forms is a requirement ? because in your case you should use Web API http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: What do you mean by "I must use asp.net web forms, it is a requirement"? "use web forms" is too vague. What is the requirement exactly?

Comment: I must use dnn as cms. Dnn is web forms based. And I want to avoid usage of asp controls or use it as low as I can. I must build app to be very responsive that is why I want to avoid large viewstates. But if this is unnatural maybe I should try to force move to asp mvc. But my first thought is like in question: web forms for view + ajax to web api for backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to implement something like SPA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

You right, you do not need ASP.NET Web Forms for this (it's too excessive IMHO). Better way is to use ASP.NET WebAPI and some view engine (like Razor) for render pages (if you need it).

**After all**: you wrote, that you MUST use ASP.NET Web Forms, and...
Yes, it is possible to use asp.net web forms without viewstate and postbacks (you just not use it, or use it to render home (index) page, ok?).

More of that, you can use both Controller and ApiController inheritors in single project, but you must to add routing for your API like this one (add this to **Application_Start** method):

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Maybe I gave wrong example of angular. I don't want single page website. I want multiple pages but with all ajax functionalities with web api as backend. Reason for this is I must use dotnetnuke as cms but as performance are crucial for app I thought that this can lead to fasterperformance.

Comment: Oh, ok then)) Anyway it is good idea to use more AJAX - you can reduce network traffic, free your server from wasteful page processing and rendering, improve user experience.  But you can also get different problems: what will happen to the browser's navigation history, will it be possible to get permalink to some ajax-based page, are your pages can be indexed by search bots?  All this problems, of course, has known solutions, but think twice: maybe some optimizations will be better than significant architecture changes?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely asp.net without view state and callbacks.  I've created a large database application doing this.  None of my dropdowns, links, etc. cause postbacks to the server (done by returning "false" on all links, ensuring that "auto postbacks" are set to false, etc.  You won't get much (if any) functionality out of the gridView control since, for pagination, that goes back to the server.  You'll have to write your own pagination / scrolling, but you can find examples on WO for that.

I *do* make extensive use of the code behind for *filling* the form on the initial load. For filling data, formatting textboxes, assigning styles, etc. the "load" and "init" events work well, and I like being able to use the "this.textbox" in the code behind.  This way I can keep the HTML on the page very limited -- the code behind does all of the heavy lifting formatting the page.

I use JQuery and JQuery UI on the front end for dialogs, tabs, etc. I picked it because it was lightweight, easy to use, and ubiquitous.   A lot of our database updates are clicking an element in a grid, popping up and blocking a dialog, retrieving the data with ajax, populating the box, unblocking the dialog.

After a lot of trial and error, I've eliminated all the parts of webforms I don't like (mostly the view state and full post back event model) and kept the parts I like a lot (the code behind to manage loading the page).

Finally -- I sure don't like the update panel.  The promise of them is great -- but it's a challenge to get them to work without goofy artifacts and they don't integrate with jQuery UI that well. Since you're going to limit/eliminate postbacks/view state, you won't be using them anyway.